# Soundcloud audio "undefined"

Tags: api, soundcloud

So I have been developing a version of the Soundcloud player on this dev server: dev.elbone.com.au/nl
While I had the player working fine I am now getting an error in regards to the audio. The track url is presenting as "undefined" on all but one track ("Odd Orbit").
Pulling my hair out here.
Just as a note tracks are only show if 'streamable' is not set to '0'.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested invaders and watchdog and they are both set to streamable=false:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/37984946?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/37984625?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

The one that worked for me (snowfaller) is set to streamable=true:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/26317984?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

Setting the non streamable to streamable should resolve the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... just been on the phone with the client and he moved the tracks to a new set. I am guessing the track then inherited that set's 'streamable' status. Does that sound right? I'm going to write in a check to the api for the 'streamable' status before writing to the page. Thanks so much for the quick reply Johannes!